# Why _gaq.push doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have 2 files

some code in main.js

```
...
var google_push = function (page, alias) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', page, 'click', alias, 1]);
}
...


    $(document).ready(function(){


        ...
        $('#some_id').click(function(e){
            google_push('value1', 'value2');
        });
        ...
```

index.html

```
<header>
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
    <!-- Google Analytics -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
</header>



<body>
...
<a id="some_id" href="#"</a>

</body>
```

So, when I click some_id link - nothing pushes to Google Analytics.
But if I rewrite code to

```
<a id="some_id" href="#" onclick = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'value1', 'click', 'value2', 1]);"</a>
```

it starts to work.
What problem can be  in the first case?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? If you set a breakpoint in `google_push`, does it trigger?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery?

Comment: Are you putting the event on a link which causes the page to unload?

Comment: 1)Yes, jQuery loaded.
2)No, there are no errors in console. Yes, alert works in google_push
3)No, there are no unload events on link.